# Named view $states not rendering templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state-management

https://plnkr.co/edit/9mFkN7oScYkKpPC0l57i?p=preview

#### Expected

After clicking <kbd>Login</kbd> and navigating to the `container` state. The named views `dashboard` and `feed` should render their templates.

#### Results

The templates for `dashboard` and `feed` do not render, nor to the logs in their controllers log.

---

#### The routerApp with login state

With the `container` module injected.

```
// RouterApp module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var tickersApp = angular.module('tickersApp', ['ui.router', 'container']);

tickersApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  const login = {
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login-template.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'l',
    controller: function($state) {
      this.login = function() {
        $state.go('container', { });
      }
    }
  }

  $stateProvider
    .state(login);
})
```

#### The container module/config and view states

Below I have the default view for container with it's template and controller, as well as 2 other named views `dashboard` and `feed`. However after clicking the <kbd>Login</kbd> and going to `container` state, none of the named views render in the markup.

```
// Container module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var container = angular.module('container', [ 'ui.router' ])
  container.config(function($stateProvider) {
    const container = {
      name: 'container',
      url: '/container',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'container-template.html',
          controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('CONTAINER view $state');
          }
        },
        'dashboard': {
          templateUrl: 'dashboard-template.html',
          controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('DASHBOARD view $state');
          }
        },
        'feed': {
          templateUrl: 'feed-template.html',
          controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('FEED view $state');
          }
        }
      }
    }
    $stateProvider.state(container);
  });
```

#### Finally the container-template.html

Below you can see both named views `dashboard` and `feed`, however their templates & controllers do not render/init.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <section>
        <!--<dashboard-module></dashboard-module>-->
        <div ui-view="dashboard"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <section>
        <!--<feed-module></feed-module>-->
        <div ui-view="feed"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still hoping for an answer as to why the named views above don't render. However I was able to get the templates for `dasboard` and `feed` to render by using absolutely named views:

https://plnkr.co/edit/XnDUIqfVuBS2Hr2N1ooy?p=preview

[image]

```
const container = {
  name: 'container',
  url: '/container',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'container-template.html',
      controller: function($scope) {
        console.log('CONTAINER view $state');
      }
    },
    'dashboard@container': {
      templateUrl: 'dashboard-template.html',
      controller: function($scope) {
        console.log('DASHBOARD view $state');
      }
    },
    'feed@container': {
      templateUrl: 'feed-template.html',
      controller: function($scope) {
        console.log('FEED view $state');
      }
    }
  }
}

$stateProvider.state(container);
```

And in the markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <section>
      <div ui-view="dashboard"></div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <section>
      <div ui-view="feed"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without the absolute naming ui-router is trying to load the `dashboard` and `feed` views into named views on `index.html`. Since the named views don't exist there they are not loaded. Once you tell ui-router to load them relative to `container` they work. It's all in the way you have structured your states.

Comment: @Lex would you mind a look at my next question regarding named views and sub states? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956873/how-to-load-a-state-view-into-a-nested-view-of-a-top-level-state