# AngularJS UI-router How to load a state view into another nested view of a top level state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

https://plnkr.co/edit/XnDUIqfVuBS2Hr2N1ooy?p=preview

[image]

I have a top level state called `container` which holds the named views `dashboard` and `feed`.

Inside of the `dashboard` view template I have a `<div ui-view="tickers"></div>` in there I want to load the `tickers` state, **how would I do that?**

Is this done by adding something into the named view `dashboard@container` ?

[image]

#### The Container module

```
// Container module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var container = angular.module('container', [ 'ui.router' ])
  container.config(function($stateProvider) {
    const container = {
      name: 'container',
      url: '/container',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'container-template.html',
          controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('CONTAINER view $state');
          }
        },
        'dashboard@container': {
          templateUrl: 'dashboard-template.html',
          controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('DASHBOARD view $state');
          }
        },
        'feed@container': {
          templateUrl: 'feed-template.html',
          controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('FEED view $state');
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider.state(container);
  });
```

#### The Container template

```
<div>
  <div class="fl w100">
    <em>Container state</em>  
  </div>

  <div ui-view="dashboard" class="fl"></div>
  <div ui-view="feed" class="fl"></div>
</div>
```

#### The Dashboard template

```
<div class="dashboard-state">
  <em>Dashbaord state</em>
  <div ui-view="tickers"></div>
</div>
```

#### The Tickers module

```
// Tickers module
var tickers = angular.module('tickers', ['ui.router'])

tickers.config(function($stateProvider) {

  const tickers = {
    parent: 'dashboard',
    name: 'tickers',
    url: '/tickers',
    params: {
      ticker: {}
    },
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'tickers-template.html',
        controller: function($scope, $state) {
          console.log('TICKERS view $state');

          $scope.tickers = [
            { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
            { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
            { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
          ];

          $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
            console.log('ticker', ticker)
            $state.go('tags', { ticker: ticker });
          }
        }
      },
      'tags@tickers': {
        templateUrl: 'tags-template.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
          console.log('TAGS view $state');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $stateProvider.state(tickers);
})
```

#### The main tickersApp module

```
// TickersApp module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var tickersApp = angular.module('tickersApp', ['ui.router', 'container', 'tickers']);

tickersApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  const login = {
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login-template.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'l',
    controller: function($state) {
      this.login = function() {
        $state.go('container', { });
      }
    }
  }

  $stateProvider
    .state(login);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still waiting on more answers, but I got this working so far by using a `tickers.component` inside of the `dashboard-template.html`

https://plnkr.co/edit/6dLIk1vq6M1Dsgy8Y4Zk?p=preview

```
<div class="dashboard-state">
  <div class="fl w100">
    <em>Dashbaord state</em>  
  </div>

  <!--<div ui-view="tickers"></div>-->
  <tickers-module></tickers-module>
</div>
```

---

```
tickers.component('tickersModule', {
  templateUrl: 'tickers-template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('TICKERS component');
    $scope.tickers = [
      { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
      { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
      { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
    ];

    $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
      console.log(' Ticker clicked!', $state)
      $state.go('tags', { ticker: ticker });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use different states on the container like these:

$stateProvider
        .state('container', {
            url: '/container',
            templateUrl: ''
        })

```
    .state('container.feed', {
        url: '/container/feed',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
    })

    .state('container.dashboard', {
        url: '/container,
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
    })
```

And use ui-sref

Comment: I want to avoid `ui-sref` and use `$state.go` inside of all the Controllers. Ok so if I go with the above, still my question remains, how to I implement the tickers state inside of the dashboard state? Could you fork a plnkr?